# Ocaml "in" keyword and usage

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm reading some notes and came across this code which looks quite clean for me:

```
# let sigma f m =
  let rec sum (i, z) =
  if i = m then z else sum(i+1, z+.f i)
  in sum(0, 0.0);;
val sigma : (int -> float) -> int -> float = <fun>
# sigma (function k -> float (k*k)) 10;;
- : float = 285.
```

I understand every bit  except the part where there's `in sum(0, 0.0)`. Well the problem is not actually about the `in` keyword but this: `sum(0, 0.0)`. What is that supposed to mean and why is it useful for this function to work? I did some googling and got something on the `in` keyword from the Ocaml site but this makes no sense to me. This is what I found:

```
class-expr  ::= class-path  
    ∣     [ typexpr  {, typexpr} ]  class-path  
    ∣     ( class-expr )  
    ∣     ( class-expr :  class-type )  
    ∣     class-expr  {argument}+  
    ∣     fun {parameter}+ ->  class-expr  
    ∣     let [rec] let-binding  {and let-binding} in  class-expr  
    ∣     object class-body end
```

I don't need an explanation of the actual function. What I need help with is that tiny `in sum(0, 0.0)`.

Comment: I downvoted the question but answered it because I feel that it was very confusingly asked and because any tutorial on Ocaml explains that much better than we can in a few minutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is `let` *bindings* `in` *body* ; your `in`is related to `let rec sum`

so the internal

```
let rec sum (i, z) =
if i = m then z else sum(i+1, z+.f i)
in sum(0, 0.0);;
```

is an internal tail recursive function to make a loop, the result of `sum(0,0.0)` (with that internal `sum`definition) is the result of `sigma` function.

The `sum(0,0.0)` is the starting point of the tail recursion.

I suggest you to use Ocaml's debugger, or at least to add a

```
 Printf.printf "sum i=%d z=%f\n";
```

line just after the `let rec sum(i,z) =` line.

BTW, you should code instead a sum with two arguments, not with a single argument happenning to be a couple:

```
let rec sum i  z =
if i = m then z else sum(i+1) (z+.f i)
in sum 0 0.0;;
```

BTW, I would loop with decreasing `i` and code instead

```
let sigma f m = 
  let rec sumloop i s = 
     (* Printf.printf "sumloop i=%d s=%f\n" i s ; *)
     if (i <= 0) then s
     else sumloop (i-1) (s+.f i)
  in sumloop m 0.0 ;;
```

I agree that my `sigma` function is slightly different (in particular if the argument `f` is an impure function with side-effects). I named the internal tail-recursive function `sumloop` (not just `sum`) to emphasize that it is a loop.

Your `z` formal to `sum` and my `s` formal to `sumloop` is an accumulating partial sum.

Comment: erm...you didn't answer my question. why `sum(0, 0.0)` and not for instance `sum(4, 5.5)`?